# My account name is Lucas, but it shows as Lucas-Asus. How do I remove -Asus?

Tags: user-accounts

I need to remove the -Asus sulfix from my Windows Account Name, but whenever I look I just see Lucas as username.

GTA V has a bug that crashes if the windows username contains special characters.

Looking the logs of the crash in the Event Viewer, I saw the computer name was Lucas-Asus.

This didn't work: [Windows 7 changes my account name... except it does not. How do I REALLY change my account name?](https://superuser.com/questions/717740/windows-7-changes-my-account-name-except-it-does-not-how-do-i-really-change) (no sign of -Asus sulfix)

Answer (score 1):

Lucas-Asus is not YOUR Username but your PC's aka Hostname

look either in system settings >  Computer Name and Edit there

outlined in this  microsoft  support link:

[change-computer-name on windows-7](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/change-computer-name#1TC=windows-7)

Comment: Yep, you are right. Restarting to see if it works... brb

Comment: Yes, the above is right, the name-ASUS is your hostname (default from when you installed windows). Change that and you'll be fine.

Comment: As a side note for future installs...  when asked about 'PC Name'  use what is desired at final to avoid this...